# Advanced javascript inheritance is failing - parent <- parent <- child

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I've been reading articles about bind, call, apply for almost a week now and it's still complex for me. I think I need them for this jsfiddle I wrote. However, I wasn't able to since I'm still confused.

I tried my best to write a fiddle of what I heard last week from one of our developers experiencing the issue. He wanted to display the properties of classA from a new class(classC) he made but it wasn't showing the data.

So here it goes.

There is a parent object(classA) that contains the complete properties and methods. A child(subclass like classB) of it inherits the properties from classA so inherited data plus its own data can be rendered on classB's modal.

Now, there is a requirement to add a new modal or section to display few properties from classA and properties from classB. So they made a new class called classC which inherits all information from classB. I remember they said, classC was inheriting all the properties and methods from classB but the properties it needs in classA weren't there.

Please help me with my fiddle. It will help me become a better Javascript developer. Oh, I also remember they were mentioning things like 'call' and 'super' which I am not familiar yet.

```
function classA()  {
  this.firstname = 'Donna';
  this.lastname = 'Hill';
  function getFullname () {
    return firstname + ' ' + lastname;
  }
}

function classB() {
    var childofA = new classA();
    var age = 10;
    var sex = "female";

    var bObject = {
        showFullname : function() {
            console.log(this.childofA.getFullname);
        }
    }
    return bObject;
}

function classC() {
    var childofB = new classB();
    var cObject = {
        showFullname : function() {
            console.log(this.childofB.showFullname);
        }
    }
    return cObject;
}

var c = new classC();
console.log(c.showFullname());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/01hz8933/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle Updated. http://jsfiddle.net/01hz8933/4/

```
// setup base class
function ClassA()  {
  this.firstname = 'Donna';
  this.lastname = 'Hill';
}
ClassA.prototype.showFullname = function() {
  return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
}


// first child class
function ClassB() {
  this.age = 10;
  this.sex = "female";
  ClassA.call(this); // call parent constructor
}
ClassB.prototype = Object.create(ClassA.prototype); // inherit
ClassB.prototype.constructor = ClassB; // use our constructor function


// grand child
function ClassC() {
  ClassB.call(this); // call parent constructor
}
ClassC.prototype = Object.create(ClassB.prototype); // inherit
ClassC.prototype.constructor = ClassC; // use our constructor function


var c = new ClassC();
console.log(c.showFullname());
```

There's a ton to unpack in there, but there were many things in your original that were surprising to me. Hopefully the updated fiddle provides some answers for you.

Comment: OMG, my code is very far. LOL! Ok, taking a look now. Thanks a lot thedeeno! :)

Comment: It worked really well! I also check c and I saw all the properties we have in B :D Thank you so much!!!